# Why are my 2 logos not switching correctly on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Logo one is suppose to fade out on scroll down as Logo two fades in.  The fade effect is happening but it's fading Logo one back in instead of Logo two yet giving it the CSS effects that I've assigned to Logo two.  This makes no sense.  I cannot figure out what I've done wrong.  Can someone please help me find my mistake?

```js
$(function() {
  var logo = $(".logo_Claire");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 200) {
      if (!logo.hasClass("logo_Claire_blue")) {
        logo.hide();
        logo.removeClass('logo_Claire').addClass("logo_Claire_blue").fadeIn("500");
      }
    } else {
      if (!logo.hasClass("logo_Claire")) {
        logo.hide();
        logo.removeClass("logo_Claire_blue").addClass('logo_Claire').fadeIn("500");
      }
    }

  });
});
```

```css
.logo_Claire_blue {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 75px;
  margin-left: 75px;
  /* margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px; */
  width: 70px;
}

.logo_Claire {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div id="nav" class="navbar">
    <div id="nav_left">
      <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
      <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
      <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
    </div>
    <a href="index.html" id="logo" class="fading_logo">
      <img src="images/logo_bluebird_90_cc.jpg" alt="logo1" class="logo_Claire_blue" style="display:none" />
      <img src="images/logo_6_small.png" alt="logo2" class="logo_Claire" />
    </a>
    <div id="nav_right">
      <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
      <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="contact.html">GET IN TOUCH</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Please provide us with enough code to replicate the issue. Your current snippet doesn't have any images, doesn't scroll, and doesn't include jQuery.

Comment: ...did you just edit your snippet to *remove* jQuery after someone added it for you? Please consider undoing that - we can't run your jQuery without jQuery!

Comment: @TylerRoper Why do I bother....?

Comment: Changing the classes doesn't change which image the variable `logo` contains.

Comment: The variable `logo` always contains logo 2. Your code never does anything to logo 1.

Comment: You have initialized logo variable at the top. On window scroll, all your hiding/displaying happening on this element. Consider moving it inside window scroll handler.

Comment: \*daringly edits jQuery back in\*

Comment: I didn't realize someone had added the jQuery. I thought that I had mistakenly pasted it in.  Clearly, I'm new at this. It was pointed out that I didn't include adequate code.  I disappeared for ten minutes while trying to figure out what code I needed to edit in.   Came back to having been down-voted.  It's beyond discouraging when you are trying so hard but not quite sure what code needs to be initially included.  I was struggling to figure out what was needed to replicate the issue, having never done that before.  I apologize for being new, needing help, and wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @Vienne Questions will be downvoted if they don't include a functioning snippet. It's all over the instructions, the welcome, the question helper tool, etc. Despite you taking the time to fix it - which we genuinely appreciate - you shouldn't be surprised to have some downvotes when your question was in an off-topic state for an extended period of time. It's expected the question will be "answerable" when it's posted. Given the traffic this site gets, 2 downvotes for an off-topic question is not bad at all. We've all been downvoted, try not to take it personally. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized logo variable at the top. On the window scroll, all your hiding/displaying happening on this element. Consider moving it inside window scroll handler.